# Create category so that an object can become a delegate for another that normally wouldn't be able to

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView`, and it would make my life a lot simpler if it could be a delegate for an `NSURLConnection`. I have made a category like this

```
@interface UIWebView (NSURLConnectionDelegate) <NSURLConnectionDelegate> 

//these methods are used by the NSURLConnection, and are implemented in the .m
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;

@end
```

the methods in the implementation do work, since i had another view that was the delegate before, but now i need to change it because of reasons.

i give the `NSURLConnection` a delegate like so

```
#import "UIWebView+NSURLConnectionDelegate.h"

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:webview]; //used to be self but now i need the webview to know about its own connection because there are multiple webviews
```

but none of the delegate methods get called when its a category like this.

has anyone done something like this before or does this not work because the NSURLConnection thinks that `webview` isnt actually a delegate or something?

edit to show some more code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest %@ %d", request.URL.absoluteURL.description, navigationType);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

if (!authed) {
    authed = NO; //gets set to yes when delegate methods work (also are some print outs in the delegate methods which are not printing at all)

    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:webview];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `webview` is non-null (and the right object) at the time that statement is executed?

Comment: yes very sure since that connection is inside `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've used categories to implement a delegate like this, so it does work.

Comment: ill try fiddle around some more, might have made a silly mistake somewhere

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to the connection somewhere to make sure it doesn't get deallocated? Looks like you're not assigning it to anything, so ARC is probably deallocating it somewhere along that call stack.

Comment: Since you are declaring your category to conform to `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, isn't listing `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods in your .h redundant?

Comment: @Scott yes it is, just showing for demo purposes

Comment: @Kevin, actually im not.. let me see if that helps

Comment: I tried it and it worked. The connection delegates did get called.

Comment: @Kevin nope, still not called.

Comment: @Puneet, odd i wonder what im doing wrong then

Comment: I have a feeling it has got to do with your NSURLRequest Object. 
Is it getting allocated? make sure it is not nil.

Comment: hmm, i dont think so, just put a break point there now, not showing up nil